# Почему он выводит bool значение выводит ошибку System.NullReferenceException:?

Tags: c#, winforms

Помогите разобраться с ошибкой. Создал столбец с CheckBox и хочу сделать реализацию добавления нескольких выбранных. Почему он выводит ошибку на этом этапе?

вот код:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count ; i++)
            {
                bool checkedCell = (bool)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
                if (checkedCell == true)
                {

                }
            }
```

как раз в первой строке после цикла выводит ошибку :

System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get вернул null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте dataGridView1 на null .